# Infopath Form - Cascading dropdown asking for number in the field

Tags: infopath, dropdown, cascading

I'm creating an Infopath form. I need to create 3 dropdown lists. The first one is client's name, the 2nd one is the contact we have in, and finally, the mail address associate to this contact.

So I want to choose the client, then in the contact, I want to see only the linked contact. So I use a dropdown list, with a data connection, and filter data. And I'm able to see the good choices concerning contact, email and clients.

The problem is : when I select a client in the dropdown list, **the field is getting red**, it thinks that I need to put a **number** ... I'm so confused.

Any idea about what am I doing wrong ? Feel free to ask me more details if needed.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: If I change the value of the field, and use the ID, I now get no error. But the cascading dropdown does not work =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was wrong, and my filter was wrong. I have to use the ID as a filter, and select the ID as the value of the dropdown list.

So be careful when you choose your value and your filter.

This solved my problem.